# How to change default ftp directory?

Tags: server, directory, ftp, paths, vsftpd

When I connect with FTP using a pem file it is connecting fine and by default, it is showing this directory: `/home/ubuntu`

Now I am trying to change the `/home/ubuntu` directory to `/var/www/myApplication`. I am new to Linux can anyone tell which commands I need to use?

And how can I see the default ftp path there is no `vsftpd` folder/files in my `/etc` folder?

Answer (score 7):

The ftp directory defaults to the user's `HOME` directory, so the easiest way to achieve your goal is to create a new user and set his `HOME` directory to `/var/www/myApplication`:

```
usermod -d /var/www/myApplication/ exampleuser
```

If you want to **restrict** the access to this directory you need to set

```
chroot_local_user=YES
```

in your `vsftpd.conf`. Then restart the vsftpd service with:

```
service vsftpd restart
```

See [Unix & Linux: How to create a FTP user with specific /dir/ access only on a Centos / linux installation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83221/how-to-create-a-ftp-user-with-specific-dir-access-only-on-a-centos-linux-ins)

---

There may be an even simpler way, see [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/changing-default-directory-on-vsftp-server-167202/):

> To change the default login directory for vsftpd, change the ftp user
>   home directory in `/etc/passwd`: `ftp:x:116:116:vsftpd daemon:/var/vsftpd:/bin/false`
>
> The ftp user (userID=116) home directory changed to `/var/vsftpd`.
>   This will allow the default/anonymous/unknown user to land into a specific place(/var/vsftpd).

Answer (score 4):

I am not really sure how you went about setting this up, but you need to install `vsftpd`.

Steps:

1. Install `vsftpd`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install vsftpd
   ```
2. Make backup of `vsftpd.conf`:

   ```
   sudo cp /etc/vsftpd.conf /etc/vsftpd.conf.orig
   ```
3. Setup firewall rules:

   ```
   sudo ufw allow 20/tcp
   sudo ufw allow 21/tcp
   sudo ufw allow 990/tcp
   sudo ufw allow 40000:50000/tcp
   sudo ufw status
   ```

   - Don't have firewall, then install:

     - `sudo apt-get install ufw`
     - Enable: `sudo ufw enabe`
4. Create a user and make the home directory this `/var/www/ftp/myApplication`

   - create an additional folder called `ftp` as seen above in case you need to add more folders for other users.
   - Create user:

     ```
     sudo usermod -d /var/www/ftp/myApplication ftpuser
     ```
5. Set its ownership, and be sure to remove write permissions with the following commands

   ```
   sudo chown nobody:nogroup /var/www/ftp
   sudo chmod a-w /var/www/ftp
   ```
6. Assign ownership to the `myApplication` foler to user `ftpuser`

   ```
   sudo chown ftpuser:ftpuser /var/www/ftp/myApplication
   ```
7. Setup `/etc/vsftpd.conf` add the following configurations:

   ```
   # Allow anonymous FTP? (Disabled by default).
   anonymous_enable=NO
   #
   # Uncomment this to allow local users to log in.
   local_enable=YES
   write_enable=YES

   # Prevent the FTP-connected user from accessing any files or commands outside 
   # the directory tree
   chroot_local_user=YES

   # Add a user_sub_token in order to insert the username in our local_root directory 
   # path so our configuration will work for this user and any future users that might 
   # be added

   user_sub_token=$USER
   local_root=/var/www/ftp

   # Set up the configuration so that access is given to a user only when they 
   # are explicitly added to a list rather than by default
   userlist_enable=YES
   userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.userlist
   userlist_deny=NO
   ```
8. Create and add user to the user_list:

   ```
   echo "ftpuser" | sudo tee -a /etc/vsftpd.userlist
   ```
9. Restart `daemon` to load new configurations:

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart vsftpd
   ```

Source(s):

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-for-a-user-s-directory-on-ubuntu-16-04